# Initialize struct on stack or heap ?

Tags: c

If you have  a struct in C like this:

```
struct mystruct{
        int i;
        char c;
};
```

and you do:

```
mystruct m;
m.i = 5;
m.c = 'i';
```

do you create the struct on the heap or on the stack ?

Comment: Stack. Stuff in a function is stack, stuff dynamically created is heap. This should be covered in a good basic C tutorial.

Comment: Technically, it wouldn't do anything since it needs to be `struct mystruct m;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In the stack:**

```
void func()
{
    mystruct m;
    ...
}

// The address of 'm' is within the stack memory space
```

**In the heap:**

```
void func()
{
    mystruct* m = malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
    ...
}

// The value of 'm' is an address within the heap memory space
```

**In the data-section:**

```
mystruct m;

static mystruct m;

void func()
{
    static mystruct m;
    ...
}

// The address of 'm' is within the data-section memory space
```

**In the code-section:**

```
const mystruct m;

const static mystruct m;

void func()
{
    const mystruct m;
    ...
}

void func()
{
    const static mystruct m;
    ...
}

// The address of 'm' is within the code-section memory space
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Although not directly related to your question, please  note that the above rule for `const` is not entirely accurate, as this keyword has in fact two purposes:

1. Allocate a variable in the (read-only) code-section of the program.
2. Prevent you (the programmer) from writing erroneous code, such as changing the value of a variable that you initially intended to keep constant throughout the execution of your program.

But feature #1 is really up to the compiler in use, which may place it elsewhere, depending on your project configuration. For example, sometimes you might want to declare a constant variable just for the sake of feature #2, while feature #1 is not feasible due to insufficient memory space in the code-section.

Comment: `const` won't generally affect where the variables live. Take something like `void func(char * p) { const char * cp = p; }`, where `cp` will be - and would have to be - created on the stack like any other local variable.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths: Sorry to disappoint you, but although variable `cp` will point to an address on the stack, it will be placed in the code-section (i.e., the address of `cp` will be an address in the code-section).

Comment: @Arun it still needs a `sizeof`, even if you don't like the `sizeof(mystruct)` style.

Comment: @barak: Since functions are allowed to call themselves, this won't be true. That function might recursively call itself 20 times, in which case you'd need 21 separate copies of `cp`, and the compiler cannot possibly know how many times it will be called.

Comment: @user3386109: Thank you for the correction; was not my idea to remove the `sizeof`, and I fixed it as soon as I noticed it was edited by someone else.

Comment: @barakmanos: I am so sorry.. I can't believe I missed that... probably time to look away from the monitor. Sincere apologies.

Comment: @barakmanos: ... hope the `typedef` I added is useful :-). And, of-course +1 for an answer covering multiple scenarios that were not even asked.

Comment: @Arun: Thanks (somebody just did a -1, however)... In any case, the point in this question is not the `typedef` compilation issue, so I allowed myself to remove it in order to keep the answer clear. Hope you understand that :)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths we're talking about top-level const; typically `const T t = ......` is placed in a read-only area.  In your example `cp` is not const, it doesn't matter where it's pointing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It doesn't make any difference, you could put `const int n = function_that_returns_int()` if you prefer. The value is still typically not going to be known until runtime, and an unknown number of those local variables may have to be created, so you're not going to get a single allocation in the code section, they'll be made on the stack. It's often possible to cast away const-ness or change them via a pointer. Undefined behavior, maybe, but demonstrates that they're often not in a "read-only area".

Comment: Here's [a trivial demonstration](http://ideone.com/gpBGtZ). The `const` local variable is created four separate times, on the stack, right next to the non-`const` local variable.

Comment: OK, if we initialize with constant expressions then.

Comment: Sure, if it's initialized with a literal. If the address is never taken, a sensible compiler might optimize the whole thing away entirely.

Comment: On the other hand, [here's an example of the same phenomenon with a literal initialization](http://ideone.com/NIxckw). gcc 4.7.2 doesn't seem to store these anywhere except on the stack even on `-O3`. Neither does clang.

Answer (score 2):

The stack. You have to use malloc/calloc to create a heap variable.

Comment: What about a global variable?